# Передача аргументов контроллов из класса в форму

Tags: c#

Есть класс **One.cs** в нём метод **Create** с параметрами для передачи в форму.

Пример:

```
public class One
{
 public static void Create(TextBox tb, TextBox tb2, TextBox tb3, Label lab, ...)
 {
    // Create(Тут много конроллов){...}
    tb.Text = "1"; 
    tb2.Text = "2";
    // и.т.д - На форме будет показано в каждом TextBox'te текст 1 и 2.
 } 
}
```

На форме вызываю так:

```
private void OneStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /* тут уже присваиваю имя конролам которые лежат на форме для вызова. */
   One.Create(NumberOne, NumberTwo, NumberThree, LabelNumber,);
}
```

У меня в методе `Create` много контролов для передачи, как можно упростить задачу с вызовом в форме?

Comment: Вам не кажется, что передавать контролы целиком, это неверный подход? Создайте класс с полями/свойствами, которые вам нужно (не контролы, а простые string, int, double, bool и др.) и передавайте его.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Не совсем понял, а как я буду вызывать эти string, int, double если они не контролы?!  Я вешаю метод и даю передачу на те контролы которые лежат у меня на форме а это (`NumberOne, NumberTwo,`и.т.д). Дайте пример пожалуйста)

Comment: В C# есть ООП, где вся наша логика делится на объекты (классы), со своим функционалом. К примеру у нас есть магазины, нам надо добавить новый, для этого потребуется класс `Shop`, который будет содержать в себе все, что относится к этому объекту. У магазина к примеру есть продукты, каждый продукт - это отдельный объект со своей логикой. В итоге получаем вот таких [два класса](https://hastebin.com/pegagenuva.cs). Теперь мы можем где угодно использовать эти классы, к примеру, перепишем ваш метод [Create](https://hastebin.com/coxividobo.cpp). [Использование](https://hastebin.com/onavinalav.sql).

Comment: То есть в вашем случае, я предлагаю сделать не солянку из контрлов, а полноценный объект, заполнять его и передавать в метод `Create` именно его, а там делать уже с ним что угодно...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Шикарно) Попробую, дайте как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В программирование есть такая вещь, как ООП.
 Цитата с [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):

> **Объе́ктно-ориенти́рованное программи́рование (ООП)** — методология
>   программирования, основанная на представлении программы в виде
>   совокупности объектов, каждый из которых является экземпляром
>   определённого класса, а классы образуют иерархию наследования.

То есть для нашего с вами удобства следует делать проект по принципу, где каждый объект отвечает за себя, реализует только то, что относиться именно к нему, не более.

**Пример:**
Давайте предположим, что у нас есть сеть магазинов, каждый магазин должен содержать в себе некий продукт, который он продает. Мы видим, что у нас есть два объекта, это "Магазин" и "Продукт". Давайте создадим класс под каждый из этих объектов:

- Продукт:

  ```
  public class Product
  {
      public Product(int id, string name)
      {
          Id = id;
          Name = name;
      }

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public void Show() => Console.WriteLine($"[{Id}] {Name}");
  }
  ```

Как мы видим, это обычный класс, который содержит в себе необходимые для этого объекта свойства (id, название), а также для примера метод `Show()`, который при вызове будет выдавать нам информацию об этом продукте.

- Магазин:

  ```
  public class Shop
  {
      public Shop(int id, string name, List<Product> products)
      {
          Id = id;
          Name = name;
          Products = products;
      }

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

      public void Show() => Console.WriteLine(Name);
      public void AddProduct(Product product)
      {
          if (Products == null) Products = new List<Product>();
          Products.Add(product);
      }
  }
  ```

Тут все тоже самое, объект "Магазин", для его существования нам к примеру необходимы свойства Id, Название, а также список продуктов (которые он будет продавать).

Имея эти два объекта, не что не мешает нам передавать их как нам угодно, к примеру перепишем Ваш метод `Create` так, что бы он принимал класс `Shop` и записывал его данные в `TextBox`:

```
public static void Create(Shop shop)
{
    tb.Text = shop.Id; 
    tb2.Text = shop.Name;
    //.....
}
```

Ну и давайте воспользуемся данным методом:

```
Create(new Shop(1, "Перекресток", new List<Product>()
{
    new Product(0, "Молоко"),
    new Product(1, "Печеньки")
}));
```

Вот так просто мы создали себе некое подобие магазина, где все разложено по своим местам, что дает нам много возможностей! Ну а контролы, как по мне, это чисто View часть, то есть то, что видит пользователь. Завязывать все на контролах - не есть хорошо!